# Getting an attribute from session and use it in jdbc

Tags: scala-gatling

I want to make a scenario in which I delete from my database the cases created with an attribute from a feeder.

The scenario:
def jdbcCleanUpScenario(tenant: String, userDetails: BatchableFeederBuilder[String]): ScenarioBuilder = {

```
scenario(s"JDBC CleanUP scenario $tenant")
  .feed(userDetails)
  .exec { session =>
    val involvedPartyId = session("involvedPartyUuid").as[String]
    session.set("involvedPartyId", involvedPartyId)
  }
  .exec(jdbc("Delete Cases").rawSql(s"DELETE FROM CASES_$tenant WHERE INVOLVED_PARTY_ID='$involvedPartyId'"))
```

But inside the rawSql I get the error: Cannot resolve symbol involvedPartyId

How can I get an attribute and then exec a jdbc?